# socketio python and socket_io_client flutter - no connection, no update

Tags: python, flutter, socket.io

i have a socketio running on python server - this is my emit code:

```
@socketio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    def send_time():
        while True:
            current_second = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            emit('update', {'data': current_second}, broadcast=True)
            socketio.sleep(1)  # Sleep for 1 second before sending the next event

    threading.Thread(target=send_time).start()
```

So ever second, server sends the actual time to its connected client.

In the console i get e.g.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2023 21:46:38] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2023 21:46:43] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2023 21:46:48] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2023 21:46:53] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2023 21:46:58] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

In flutter i have this code:

```
class OJICLIENTCON {

  static void connect() {
    final url = _IP;
    IO.Socket socket = IO.io(url, <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
    });

    socket.onConnect((_) {
      print('SocketIO connected');
      socket.emit('updatesAPPSCHED');
    });

    socket.on('update', (data) {
      print("update");
      print('Received update: $data');
    });
  }
}
```

I see, that, when I open the app python console starts printing these `GET` log.
In flutter i have no output.

What is wrong?